# Method does not wait for Promise to be resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a function that I'm trying to call and basically force it to wait for a response before continuing onto the next thing.

I have two functions, both are asynchronous.

The first one looks something like this, with all parameters that begin with an '_' to be used as callbacks:

```
async function formatJson(input, _sendToThirdParty, _handleLogs, _setDimensions)
{
     ...do some work here to format the payload
     if(onlineConnectionRequired)
    {
         _setDimensions(itemToUpdate, object);
    }
    else {
         // Do non-online based transformations here
    }
    ...do more work after the above
}
```

Basically from that, I'm trying to call this method setDimensions which looks like this:

```
async function setDimensions(itemToUpdate, object) {
    try
    {
        if(itemToUpdate != null)
        {
            console.log("Loading dimensions");
    
            await Promise.resolve(function() {
                ns.get(`inventoryItem/${object['Item ID']}?expandSubResources=true`)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log("Inventory Item Loaded. Updating dimensions...");

                    itemToUpdate.consignments.push(
                        {
                            consignmentID: object.conID,
                            barcode: object.barcode,
                            itemID: '', // leaving as empty for now
                            width : res.data.custitem_width,
                            length : res.data.custitem_length,
                            height : res.data.custitem_height,
                            weight : res.data.custitem_weight,
                            fragile: object.fragile === 'T' ? 1 : 0,
                            description: object.description
                        }
                    );

                    console.log("Dimensions Finalised");
                })
            });
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
        const message = `Error attempting to set the dimensions for ${object['Item ID']}`;
        console.log(message);
        throw new Error(message);
    }
}
```

The problems I'm coming across are:

1. The code from the first method continues on before waiting for the promise to resolve, but I need it to wait so I can fully finish building up the payload before it continues on doing the next bits
2. If I try and include the `await` keyword before my call to `_setDimensions(...)` in the first method, I get an error **"SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"**, but I would've thought that it *was* an async function?

If anyone could help, that would be incredibly appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: use the promise constructor not `Promise.resolve`

Comment: `ns.get` looks to return a promise already

Comment: Is ``_setDimensions`` parameter for callback in first function is calling second function? Or is it just a naming preference for your callback function? Secondly, why don't you use a single callback and continue on working depending on the callback data?

Comment: Does the function `_setDimentions` return a Promise? Second, `await Promise.resolve()`　may resolve immediately before callback completes. You should use `new Promise()` instead.

Comment: "*I would've thought that it was an async function?*" - yes, `formatJson` is an `async function`. Please show us the exact code you tried, without any elisions.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN It's a naming preference but basically it calls the method. I was just trying to play around with running it as a callback and using await, or just as a method (doing either way in the end yields the same result). With using the single callback and working depending on the callback data, how would you do that? I think that's what I'm struggling with, making sure that code in method 1 waits for this method to return the resolved promise before it continues. Sometimes I'll need it do query an online system, sometimes I wont.

Comment: @Yvonne I understand. I can solve this problem but before I need to know one more thing. As you have mentioned in your last comment ``_setDimentions`` is supposed to be callback function, but it will also call your second method. Is that right?

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN that would be correct, it is meant to be a callback function but yeah it basically calls that second method there

Comment: @Yvonne okay, I got it. I will post the solution for what you want to do.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Yvonne you are welcome, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

The correct design of your functions are below:

```
formatJson(input, (err, value) => {
    if(err) {
        // Error handler goes here
        //console.log(err);
        throw err;
    } else {
        // Implementation for working with returned value
        console.log(value);
    }
});

function formatJson(input, callback)
{
    //...do some work here to format the payload
    if(onlineConnectionRequired)
    {

        setDimensions(itemToUpdate, object)
            .then((updatedItem) => {
                // Implement anything here to work with your
                // result coming from setDimensions() function

                //console.log(updatedItem);

                // Callback with null error and updatedItem as value
                callback(null, updatedItem);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                // Callback with err object and null value
                callback(err, null);
            });
    }
    else {
         // Do non-online based transformations here
    }
    //...do more work after the above
}

function setDimensions(itemToUpdate, object) {
    try
    {
        if(inventoryItemID != null)
        {
            console.log("Loading dimensions");
    
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                ns.get(`inventoryItem/${object['Item ID']}?expandSubResources=true`)
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log("Inventory Item Loaded. Updating dimensions...");

                        itemToUpdate.consignments.push(
                            {
                                consignmentID: object.conID,
                                barcode: object.barcode,
                                itemID: '', // leaving as empty for now
                                width : res.data.custitem_width,
                                length : res.data.custitem_length,
                                height : res.data.custitem_height,
                                weight : res.data.custitem_weight,
                                fragile: object.fragile === 'T' ? 1 : 0,
                                description: object.description
                            }
                        );

                        console.log("Dimensions Finalised");

                        resolve(itemToUpdate);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => reject(err));
            });
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
        const message = `Error attempting to set the dimensions for ${object['Item ID']}`;
        console.log(message);
        throw new Error(message);
    }
}
```

Mistakes in your code:

1. Your `formatJson` function had `async` keyword but your `formatJson` function had callback functions named `_sendToThirdParty, _handleLogs, _setDimensions`. There are 3 types of implementation to create asynchronous codes. You can use callbacks, Promises or async/await. But Promises and async/await are the same except their uses cases and syntaxses. When you define a function as `async fn() {...}` it basically return a new Promise, so it is equal saying `fn() { return new Promise(); }`. Functions with callbacks have a shape like `function(params, callback) { callback(cbParams); }` you can use call callback function in a several branches in your function. But you only have single callback function, your code had 3 callback functions. Also note that functions with callback don't have `async` keyword. This is not valid because as I mentioned earlier, an **async function** will return a Promise. So you *should not (but you can)* define a function as `async function(params, callback)` like you did in your first method. This is definition is not wrong and it can work but it's not valid.
2. Your second method was an async function which was returning nothing. So I have changed it to normal function with returning a Promise.

Answer (score -2):

Is the `formatJson` method beeing called inside an async method? It need to be, and before _setDimensions you need to add a `await` keyword.
And, as Daniel said, use the promise constructor.

Comment: It is not required to use ``formatJson`` in an async function, you can use it as ``formatJson.then().catch()`` in a sync (normal) function. What async keyword added before a function declaration do is it makes your async function to return a Promise.